# How can I understand this For-Loop? (Difficulty fully understanding For-Loops)

Tags: python, for-loop

In my Python textbook they have created a 'Hangman' game. Full source: http://pastebin.com/k1Fwp7zJ

I am having **tremendous** difficulty understanding the following code snippet:

```
new = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
    if guess == word[i]:
        new += guess
    else:
        new += so_far[i]
so_far = new
```

I don't know exactly what "i" is. I also don't know how to "say"/imagine the For-Loop in English. I cannot understand/imagine what is happening in this code segment, even though I've done all of the preparation in this chapter and gotten everything correct so far.

**In my planning/algorithm** for this part of the Hangman game, I've written:

*"Go through each character of the word and check if the guessed letter is in the word. If the guessed letter is in the word, note its position(s). 
Then go to the above positions in "so_far", and replace with the guessed letter."*

I literally have a headache trying to understand this section of code. When I try to write the hangman game myself, I always get stuck here and I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe someone has been in a similar situation as me. Can someone explain what this For-loop means? And perhaps a way to understand the rest of the code here?

Comment: `i` is a variable, in this case an int.  Range takes an int `n`, in this case n=the length of word, and gives you a list of numbers from 0-(n-1).  `for i in range(n)` will iterate through from 0 to n-1.  So if word is hello, `range(len(hello))` is `[0,1,2,3,4]` and `i` will step through these values at each loop step.  Everything inside this loop will be run for each value of `i`.

Comment: A loop, conceptually, just means "repeat this block of code".  Loops can be conditional (a `while` loop runs as long as a condition holds) or they can be numeric (repeat this block N times).  For loops are the second instance.

Comment: i in this case is a variable, a reference if you will to every single alphabet in the word.  word[i] refers to the letter at the index i.  Think of it this way, a word, example:  "HANGMAN" has indices for each letter in the word.  In this case, the indices start at 0-1-2-3-4-5-6  so there are a total of 7 letters, each have an index (i) and it starts from 0.  i takes that value 0 to 6

Comment: It's probably not helped by the fact that this is very bad (non-Pythonic) code.

Comment: argh `range(len())`... ARGH

Answer (score 0):

> "I don't know exactly what `i` is"

`i` is the name to which each item in `range` is assigned. The first time through the loop, `i == 0`. The second time, `i == 1`, and so on.

> "I don't know how to "say"/imagine the `for`-Loop in English."

A `for` loop in Python has two parts; the name(s) to assign to, and the iterable(s) to iterate through. For each value in the iterable, the loop runs once*, assigning that value to the provided name.

Your example is a relatively simple one:

```
for i in range(...):
```

Here `range(start[, stop[, step]])` provides the integers in each `step` from `start` to `stop` (not inclusive). You have only a `stop`, so the default `start=0` and `step=1` are used, giving:

```
range(n) ~= [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1, n]
```

Each of these values in assigned, in turn, to the name `i`, allowing you to access them inside the loop.

* unless you `break` out, `return` or an error is `raise`d

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops follow this simple design:

[image]

Let's break this line down:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
```

First, let's look at:

```
for i
```

The keyword `for` is known as a loop.  It will repeat/iterate the same chunk of code until the condition is met.  The `i` is the current variable(in this case, numeric variable).  Imagine someone say, write the numbers from 1 to 10, then your `i` will go from the number 1 to the number 10.

```
in
```

The keyword `in` will be declaring the range of values the previous variable `i` will equal.  Let's break down this:

```
range(len(word))
```

This translate to the ***range*** values of the ***length***  of the variable `word`.  Say the the `word` equals to "hello", then length is 5.  This means the range of 5 is 0,1,2,3,4 (***range*** excludes the final value).

Basically, this:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
```

Means:

```
iterate the variable `i` from the range of the length of the the variable `word`.
```

A simple test to see what `i` is to change the code to:

```
new = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
    print i #this will print the values
    if guess == word[i]:
        new += guess
    else:
        new += so_far[i]
so_far = new
```

Remember, there are plenty of tutorials online:

- [Link 1](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop/)
- [Link 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)
- [Link 3](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-for-loop-examples-statements/)

Answer (score 0):

```
new = ""
```

This line creates an empty string

```
for i in range(len(word)):
```

In this line the code tells the interpreter for every number in the range 0 up to the length (obtained by the `len()` funciton) of `word -1` do the code that follows.

For example `len('Thing')` would be 5. Now the interpreter will do whatever is inside the `for` loop 5 times if the code was:

```
for i in range(len('thing')):
    print('Hello, world')
```

`Hello, world` would be printed 5 times. In Python you don't need to increment `i` like you do in other languages. So when the loop starts `i == 0` after it goes through the if/else block it will be incremented to 1 automatically.

```
if guess == word[i]:
```

This line checks to see if the variable `guess` is equal to the value of `word` at index `i`. For example if `word = 'thing'` then `word[0]` would be `t`. Computers start counting from 0 not 1, so `word[4]` would be `g`.

```
  new += guess
```

This line is shorthand for `new = new + guess`. Since we are working with strings the `+` operator wil concatenate them, or glue them together. For example `'a' + 'b'` would be `ab`.

```
else:
```

This line indicates what to do if the `if` condition is not met. For example:

```
if some_number > 10:
    print('hello')
else:
    print('Bye')
```

If `some_number` was greater than 10 hello would print. If not Bye would print.

```
 new += so_far[i]
```

This line concatenates new and whatever is at index i in so_far.

```
so_far = new
```

This sets `so_far` equal to new.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, Python's range() function takes an integer (here, the length of the word you're trying to guess) and returns a list of integers from 0 to that number.* So:

```
word = "example"
len(word) //equals 7
range(len(word)) //returns [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Lists in Python are iterable data types. This means that you can iterate over the elements, i.e. move over the elements one at a time and do something to each one. First it sets i to 0, then does whatever is contained in the body of the for-loop. Then it sets i to 1 and does whatever is contained in the body of the for loop again. And it keeps going until it reaches the end of the list. So with your example:

```
word = "example"
for i in range(len(word))
```

You're telling Python to do something on each element i in the list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]. There's nothing special about "i" here. You can name it whatever you want, but it's just a conventional shorthand notation used to reference the element later. For example:

```
for i in range(3):
    print "The number is " + i
```

This prints:

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
```

In Python, strings can be accessed by index. So for example:

```
word = "example"
word[0] = "e"
word[1] = "x"
. . .
```

Couple this with the for-loop, and you have:

```
word = "example"
myWordLength = len(word)
for i in range(myWordLength):
    print "The letter is " + word[i]
```

And this with print:

```
The letter is e
The letter is x
The letter is a
The letter is m
The letter is p
The letter is l
The letter is e
```

Range(), for-loops and lists can do lots of other things too but hopefully that helps you understand the assignment.